# Sharepoint 2013: Access CA by localhost, not hostname

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm standing up a new development SP 2013 standalone site on Windows 2012 R2.  Not much has been done with this environment.  My problem is that I can only access Central Admin by localhost:port, not my hostname:port.

I've looked at various posts suggesting DisableLoopbackCheck or adding hostname & FQDN to BackConnectionHostNames, but that still hasn't resolved my issue.

When I go to localhost:port, no credentials required.
When I go to hostname:port, prompt for credentials but never accepted.
When I go to 127.0.0.1:port, prompt for credentials and accepted.

Let me preface all this with after the installation completes for SP, the Product Conf Wizard will never complete for me.  It always fails at "Failed to create sample data."  I read that manually sharing the Analytics_GUID dir and updating the ACL would be a part of the solution, but the directory is never created.  So when that fails, I proceeded to go to CA and that's where I run into the current problem.  Maybe it's all related.

Anyone have any suggestions as I'm at my wits end.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think first make sure Config wizard completed sucessfully, could you pelase put the complete error you are getting?

Comment: The original wizard reported

   Failed to create sample data
<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied"

   But when I run it again, I get

   Failed to create sample data.  An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: did you try to add the Permission to Analytics GUID folder try to add everyone with full control?

Comment: I wish I could but that directory doesn't ever get created.  In C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server, I only have \Applications and \CanonicalResources

Comment: check this link http://sachintana.blogspot.ca/2012/08/install-sharepoint-2013-preview-on.html

Comment: One thing about that is I'm using SQL Express so I'm unable to start the Agent service.  Maybe I should try to install SQL Standard.  I suppose it's worth a shot.

Comment: are you using server or foundation version of sharepoint?

Comment: This is the Server version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my problem is quite simple.  Stand-alone installation is a POS.  I installed SQL 2012 Standard and have had no issues whatsoever going through the installation and Product Configuration wizard.

Comment: This was my experience also. Note that there are several posts which refer to the Analytics_GUID share - That share is not present in Foundation version installations. The solution is install SQL Server Express separately and choose Farm installation (even if SQL is on the same machine).